# delete all drush installations

Tags: drush

I've built a Drupal 8 site without using Drush because I was couldn't figure out how to uninstall, or upgrade, the 5.7-drush on my computer.

I can't remember which method I installed Drush by in the first place and every time I've had Drush 8 working my system has reverted back to 5.7 on the next restart/boot.

I've tried extensive googling of course but haven't found a solution yet that permanently removed my old drush.

Any tips?

Comment: `ls -l \`which drush\`` should tell you where it is, then just delete the target and the symlink. If there's no symlink, just delete the file itself

Comment: Fantastic. How do I see if there's a symlink and how d I delete that?

Comment: If it's a symlink the output will contain something like `/path/to/symlink -> /path/to/target`. You can delete it like any normal file

Comment: Gotcha, seems to be all gone now. THanks for the help Clive. You should post it as an answer so I can give you some points for your help